# Questions on use ginput and print the results with python

Tags: python

I would like to use `ginput` function in python to get two points from the figure and get the closest int value and save the array. The code is shown below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pylab import plot, ginput, show, axis

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t = np.arange(10)
plt.plot(t, np.sin(t))
print("Please click")
x = ginput(2)
x=np.ceil(x)
**print (x)**
plt.show()
```

When I run the code and print the x with brackets, the output is:

```
Please click
[[ 2.  1.]
 [ 8. -0.]]
```

However, if I run the code and print `x` without the brackets,

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pylab import plot, ginput, show, axis

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t = np.arange(10)
plt.plot(t, np.sin(t))
print("Please click")
x = ginput(2)
x=np.ceil(x)
**print x**
plt.show()
```

the output shows error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-27-1d992b01e790>", line 1
    print x
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am really confused about this. What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function, therefore it requires parentheses around its input argument like any other function.